# VS2022 ENC0021 ENC0036 purple underline waves

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am getting these warnings all the time ENC0021 ENC0036

> modifying a generic method requires restarting application

And all the code gets purple wavy underlines,
the problem persists after rebuilds.

I tried adding this in the csproj, but it makes no difference:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NoWarn>ENC0036;ENC0021</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

anybody knows how to get rid of these warnings

Comment: [Known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-gives-enc-issues-even-after-full-rebuild/1592229), best to file your own feedback report so they have a shot at a repo.  Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: I actually did that